# I need to pass variable from my python script to a remote server

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python, I need to pass variable from my python script to a remote server where I am trying to create a file through it. Below is part of my code.

```py
   DOMAIN='google.com'

   stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_client.exec_command('echo export test=https://abc.DOMAIN:80/ > test.sh')
   stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_client.exec_command('echo export test=http://abc.DOMAIN:80/ > test.sh')
   stdin.write(DOMAIN)
   stdin.flush()
```

I am trying to pass DOMAIN variable as stdin in the exec_command but it is not working, i am not sure if it is correct way but any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's not working now is that it it evaluating the string as the literal word 'DOMAIN' rather than the value you have assigned the variable with that name.

You can add a variable to a string in a few ways:

```
f"echo export test=https://abc.{DOMAIN}:80/ > test.sh"
```

or

```
"echo export test=https://abc.{}:80/ > test.sh".format(DOMAIN)
```

or

```
"echo export test=https://abc." + DOMAIN + ":80/ > test.sh"
```

Comment: First option will work in python 3.6+. Second in python 3.5+, and the last one in all versions.